# How can I backup my settings and widgets on Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, backup, settings, widgets

I need to backup my Kubuntu settings and widgets only so I can use them on Ubuntu.

In the backup software, it doesn't let me backup the root folder. I attempted to backup folder by folder, but it gives me an error on the important ones such as `proc` or VirtualBoxe folders.

I tried ChatGPT, but it wasn't very helpful.

I want to change from Kubuntu to Ubuntu, and I need my settings to be backed up. I can copy files with no problem, but I need some further assistant with the root folder.

I'm a newbie so please do not explain in an advanced way.

Comment: Settings are not compatible between Ubuntu and Kubuntu, so you're asking for something impossible.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, i honestly didnt know that :D appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to backup data on Kubuntu so that you can later use it on another Kubuntu (NOT Ubuntu) installation, then copy the contents of `$HOME/.local` and `$HOME/.config`, and paste them in the new installation.

---

Do not try this on Ubuntu. It does not support Kubuntu's widgets.